# How do I make a protocol that my generic class can conform to?

Tags: swift

I have a class along these lines:

```
class FooKeyValueStore<T: Codable> {
    func set(key: String, value: T) throws {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

That I'd like to abstract behind a protocol.  How can I define such a protocol please?  I've tried the obvious approach of:

```
protocol KeyValueStore<Item> {
    associatedtype Item where Item == Codable
    
    func set(key: String, value: Item) throws
}
```

but the compiler complains that the class doesn't conform to the protocol.

Any help much appreciated!  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
associatedtype Item where Item == Codable
```

This line is incorrect. You don't mean `Item == Codable`. You mean `Item: Codable`.